# Facebook Like button not showing up on wordpress site with jetpack

Tags: facebook, wordpress, facebook-like, jetpack

Ok guys. I am not a WordPress or much of a PHP man. I know I need to be but I wasn't raised that way. I ran into a problem lately. Our Facebook like button won't show up. I don't know why. We are using jetpack version 2.3.1 and the tweet and Google plus button work fine. I can see that the Facebook iFrame button is there but it is empty. I inspect it with chrome and find that the URL for that, when I open it in a new window, shows me nothing. Any ideas? I've tried installing the 'Facebook Like Button' plug in but that didn't show up and I can't seem to find a good source. I've been searching around for a few days now.

Here is the URL from one of the posts that is in the Facebook iFrame button https://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?api_key=&locale=en_US&sdk=joe%E2%80%A6ton_count&colorscheme=light&show_faces=false&extended_social_context=false

Here is the site I'm working on: [Site](http://www.gunnews.com)

I believe the problem lies with this code here:

```
<div class="like_btn">
<fb:like href="<?php echo urlencode(get_permalink($post->ID)); ?>" layout="button_count" show_faces="false" width="100" font=""></fb:like>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem and apparently it needs to be within an iframe.

Try this code:

```
<div class="like_btn"><iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=<?php echo urlencode(get_permalink($post->ID)); ?>&layout=button_count&show_faces=false&action=like&colorscheme=light" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:100px; height:30px"></iframe>
</div>
```